# Can TIdHTTPServer and TIdHTTP in same executable connect?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy

I have a program which uses a TIdHTTPServer. Now I want to write some automated tests using a TIdHTTP which talks to the TIdHTTPServer. The test code is in the program itself.

When the TIdHTTP tries to connect a 'Socket Error # 10061 Connection refused.' exception is raised. I'm guessing that's beacuse the TIdHTTPServer is using the port already.

Is it possible for a TIdHTTPServer and a TIdHTTP which are in the same executable to talk to each other at all? If so, how?

Comment: You can have a TCP server and client in the same application. Perhaps your firewall solution is blocking your server?

Comment: Thanks iMan. It appears my app was allowed to go through the firewall already.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they can run in the same executable and connect to each other.  Simply specify (one of) TIdHTTPServer's listening IP(s) in the URL that you pass to TIdHTTP, eg:

```
with IdHTTPServer1.Binding.Add do
begin
  IP := '127.0.0.1';
  Port := 80;
end;
IdHTTPServer1.Active := True;
...
IdHTTP1.Get('http://127.0.0.1/');
```

Comment: Ah, that works indeed. But my real code doesn't. I'm going to look into that!